# How do you do a mass payment in sandbox mode with java and the paypal api?

Tags: java, paypal

I have been looking all over today for examples/tutorial/documentation
which explains how to do a mass payment with the paypal api and java. I have checked the paypal website, although all I see are overviews of what mass payments are and a theoretical explanation of how they work and why they exist. Is there any resource/tutorial that shows how to do a mass payment with java and the paypal api with actual code and/or java documentation that clearly explains what is required to make a mass payment in sandbox mode? I would be very appreciative of any help with this.

Comment: Hello Dan, were you able to integrate the API and find some samples? It'll be good if you can share some of the work here as well.

Comment: @ShubhamA. I would love to share work if I had it. From a business point of view it made more sense to file the batch payment manually, instead of automate that process, so I did not go further with this... Still would be interested if somebody solves this and cares to share though!

Comment: I was able to do this myself, using the documentation and Github examples. Below is a tested answer which works.

Answer (score 2):

I integrated Mass Payout API with Spring Boot. Here are the main excerpts without any dependency on the framework though.

To start, we add suitable `Maven` dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, we can create a `Payout` object and add multiple recipients as `PayoutItem` like:

```
Payout payout = new Payout();

PayoutSenderBatchHeader senderBatchHeader = new PayoutSenderBatchHeader();
senderBatchHeader.setEmailSubject("PayPal Email Header");

Currency amount = new Currency();
//Transaction of 1 unit with US Dollars as unit.
amount.setValue("1").setCurrency("USD");
```

Once that is done, you can start adding recipients:

```
PayoutItem sendTo = new PayoutItem();

//This can be "Phone" and specify PayPal mobile number on setReceiver
sendTo.setRecipientType("Email")
       .setReceiver("user@email.com")
       .setNote("Thanks.").setAmount(amount);

List<PayoutItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add(sendTo);
//Add more recipients to items list but with same currency as handling
//different currencies in single batch isn't possible

payout.setSenderBatchHeader(senderBatchHeader).setItems(items);
```

Now that, it is done, finally execute the request:

```
//paypalMode can be either "sandbox" or "live"
APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(
  paypalClientId, paypalClientSecret, paypalMode);

PayoutBatch batch = payout.create(apiContext);
String batchId = batch.getBatchHeader().getPayoutBatchId();
```

Payment request has been executed now, but asynchronously. Check JSON string response as:

```
String jsonResponseStr = Payout.getLastResponse();
```

In this response, you can find a `link` which needs to be accessed for details about this Payout, if it was successful or not.

It is worth noticing that **synchronous processing is not supported** for multiple recipients at once now by Paypal.

Comment: payout.create(apiContext, params) need two args, payout.createSynchronous(apiContext) takes only one arg.

Comment: How you were able to test mass payment with an account did you created another new developer account to test mass payment??

Comment: Never mind found this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/api-integration/#test-payouts